# Prove $u(x)$ to be a polynomial

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Is this statement true?

If a map $u:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfies

$$\pi\dfrac{u_{xx}+u_{yy}}{\int_\Omega u \,d\Omega} \text{ is constant with } \Omega=\{(x,y,z_0): x^2+y^2=1\} \subset \mathbb{R}^2\times\{z_0\} \text{ for all } z_0\in\mathbb{R} \tag 1$$

$$u_{xx}(x,y)=u_{yy}(y,x) \tag 2$$

$$u_{z}=0 \tag 3$$

$$u(\cos(\phi),\sin(\phi),z)=0 \text{ for every } \phi\in[0,2\pi),\ z \in \mathbb{R} \tag 4 $$

then $u$ is a polynomial of grade two or less.

Thank you.